# QML: button with image and text underneath

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create a button like control in QML which displays an image and also some text under it. My current attempt stands as follows:

```
  Item {
        id: button
        width: 30
        height: 100
        property alias text: buttontext
        signal clicked

        Image {
            id: visualImage
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "qrc:/images/test.png"
        }

        Text {
            id: buttontext
            font.bold: true
            text: "Test"
        }
    }
```

This has a lot of problems unfortunately. So, at the moment, I am specifying the width and height of the item but this should be calculated based on the width and height of the image and the text. Also, the text is shown at the top and inside the image where I would like to position the text under the image, centered with image horizontally with some margins.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you want. The simplest would be using [`Button`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html)(<-clickable) class of qml and specify it's icon, text and style options.
You can also create `MouseArea` with `Image` and `Text` inside (you can specify `z` option to make `Text` to be drawn under `Image`).
You can also create your own component, though it may be overkill in most situations.

Comment: Take a look at  `Column`, it's really easy to use. Set `witdh:parent.width` to both image and text and also set `horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter` to the text: that's it.

Comment: This is a great suggestion!

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I followed your suggestion and was able to get something working. Do you want to write it as an answer, so I can accept it and give you credit?

Answer (score 3):

You must use anchors in the Image and in the Text. Example:

```
Item {
        id: button
        width: 30
        height: 100
        property alias text: buttontext
        signal clicked

        Image {
            id: visualImage
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: buttontext.top
            source: "qrc:/images/test.png"
        }

        Text {
            id: buttontext
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            font.bold: true
            text: "Test"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the direction I was going in initially but I will probably try the `Column` idea suggested in the comment first as it looks simpler!

Answer (score 2):

Since QtQuick.Controls 2.3 (Qt 5.10), [display](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#display-prop) property was introduced:

> This property determines how the icon and text are displayed within the button.

For your case it's `AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon`

Answer (score 0):

Something I have done in the past as a workaround for this,

create a `Rectangle{……}` which holds all the 'Button' items, (Text/Image Ect),

It may not be the prettiest way but there is a few variations

1. Create the 'Image' and 'text' externally (photoshop whatever you choose) then fill your `Rectangle` with the content, then also set a `MouseArea { onClicked {……}}` event to that,
2. Make a `Column/Grid/Row` within the `Rectangle` and position your items using that method